# The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. Missing potential exception handling

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a web application that is failing upon login when calling EF's OnModelCreating function. Within the foreach loop contained in the **BaseDbContext.cs** code snippet below.

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(configurationInstance)
```

From what I can tell, the typesToRegister is a key/value pair where a list of 90 assemblies are listed within the Results View. Upon analysis of the Results View, there are 80 key/value pairs that seem to load fine, but items 81 through 90 are where the exception begins to get thrown. This is where the value for the key field is: `Name = "<>C"`.

Valid record example:

```
{Name = "PayableMap" FullName = "Galaxy.DatabaseMapping.Accounting.PayableMap"}
```

Exception record example:

```
{Name = "<>c" FullName = "Galaxy.DatabaseMapping.Security.GroupMap+<>c"}
```

I tried adding an `if(!type.Name != "<>C")` within the foreach loop, but that did not work. I tried searching for this result on the web but didn't have any luck. Does anyone know why the typesToRegister appears to have invalid records? Is this a problem that I need to swim upstream to figure out why the typesToRegister is loading bad values or do I just need to add proper exception handling? Note: I am unable to step-in to the code that populates typesToRegister.

**SecurityDataContext.cs**

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        RunConventions(modelBuilder, typeof(GalaxyUserMap));
    }
```

**BaseDbContext.cs**

```
    public void RunConventions(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder, Type assemblyClassType)
    {
        // Change default conventions for cascade deletes
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        // Id property in everyclass is named class + Id  (i.e CustomerId, JobId, VendorId)
        // Id is always first column in table
        // Could also explicitly determine as key using .Configure(p => p.IsKey() but EF already looks for property of name Id as primary key
        modelBuilder.Properties()
          .Where(p => p.Name == "Id")
          .Configure(p => p.HasColumnOrder(0).HasColumnName((p.ClrPropertyInfo.ReflectedType == null ? "" : p.ClrPropertyInfo.ReflectedType.Name) + "Id"));

        // Add Domain Entity Mapping Configurations
        var typesToRegister = Assembly.GetAssembly(assemblyClassType).GetTypes()
          .Where(type => type.Namespace != null);
        foreach (Type type in typesToRegister)
        {
            dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(configurationInstance); // The error occurs here.
        }
    }
```

**GalaxUserMap.cs**

```
   public class GalaxyUserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<GalaxyUser>
    {
        public GalaxyUserMap()
        {
            Property(galaxyUser => galaxyUser.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
            HasOptional(galaxyUser => galaxyUser.DeactivatedBy)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(galaxyUser => galaxyUser.DeactivatedById);
            HasOptional(galaxyUser => galaxyUser.CustomerInvoiceSearchCriteria).WithRequired(userCustomerInvoiceCriteria => userCustomerInvoiceCriteria.User);
            HasOptional(galaxyUser => galaxyUser.JobSearchCriteria).WithRequired(userJobSearchCriteria => userJobSearchCriteria.User);
            HasOptional(galaxyUser => galaxyUser.VendorSearchCriteria).WithRequired(userVendorSearchCriteria => userVendorSearchCriteria.User);
            HasOptional(galaxyUser => galaxyUser.CustomerSearchCriteria).WithRequired(userCustomerSearchCriteria => userCustomerSearchCriteria.User);
            HasOptional(galaxyUser => galaxyUser.CustomerContactSearchCriteria).WithRequired(customerContactUserSearchCriteria => customerContactUserSearchCriteria.User);
            HasOptional(galaxyUser => galaxyUser.PayableSearchCriteria).WithRequired(payableSearchCriteria => payableSearchCriteria.User);
            HasOptional(galaxyUser => galaxyUser.ReceiptSearchCriteria).WithRequired(receiptSearchCriteria => receiptSearchCriteria.User);
            Ignore(galaxyUser => galaxyUser.Status);
            ToTable(DatabaseConstants.GalaxyUsersTableName);
        }
    }
```

**GalaxyUser.cs**

```
    public class GalaxyUser : Person
    {
        public virtual GalaxyUserCustomerInvoiceSearchCriteria CustomerInvoiceSearchCriteria { get; set; }
        public virtual GalaxyUserJobSearchCriteria JobSearchCriteria { get; set; }
        public virtual GalaxyUserPayableSearchCriteria PayableSearchCriteria { get; set; }
        public virtual GalaxyUserReceiptSearchCriteria ReceiptSearchCriteria { get; set; }
        public virtual GalaxyUserCustomerSearchCriteria CustomerSearchCriteria { get; set; }
        public virtual GalaxyUserCustomerContactSearchCriteria CustomerContactSearchCriteria { get; set; }
        public virtual GalaxyUserVendorSearchCriteria VendorSearchCriteria { get; set; }
        public bool IsVendorHeaderCollapsed { get; set; }
        public bool IsCustomerHeaderCollapsed { get; set; }
        public bool IsJobHeaderCollapsed { get; set; }
        public int JobMilestonesWorklistDaysOut { get; set; }
        public int JobItemsWorklistDaysOut { get; set; }
        public int JobsWorklistDaysOut { get; set; }
        public int? DeactivatedById { get; set; }
        public virtual GalaxyUser DeactivatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DeactivatedDate { get; set; }
        public PersonStatusTypes Status { get { return DeactivatedDate.HasValue ? PersonStatusTypes.Inactive : PersonStatusTypes.Active; } }

        public bool IsSystemAdmin {
            get { return RoleNames.Contains(Roles.Administer_System); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: which line has an issue point that out, this issue is related to the generics type inference, where for a method call type cannot be known ?

Comment: Can you show us your GalaxyUserMap entity please? @MrinalKamboj, it is happening inside his foreach loop.

Comment: @Dimitri I have updated my question to include both the GalaxyUserMap and the EntityTypeConfiguration<GalaxyUser> extension. There are further extensions from GalaxyUser. How far down the rabbit hole do you want to go?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0411