# Assembly.GetAssembly().GetTypes() returns duplicates

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is an extension to a previously asked question: [The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. Missing potential exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55254715/the-type-arguments-cannot-be-inferred-from-the-usage-try-specifying-the-type-ar)

I am attempting to debug an existing ASP.NET web application and am getting an exception when logging in:

> The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. Missing potential exception handling

From what I can tell, the error occurs because there are **duplicate** assemblies loaded into `varTypesToRegister` when the following code is ran:

```
 var typesToRegister = Assembly.GetAssembly(assemblyClassType).GetTypes()
          .Where(type => type.Namespace != null)
```

There are 91 elements in the Results View and the last 10 appear to be duplicates as they already existing within the first 0 - 80 items in the array/list. The first exception is thrown on element 81 (see screenshot below). As you can see, element 81 already exists as element 24. So, an exception is thrown when an already existing assembly is attempted to be added to modelBuilder.

[image]

Note: `assemblyClassType` is only one assembly that is passed in. This code seems to get all project assemblies, though I am not sure how or why that is happening (I am new to this project and the original developer is unavailable).

Question: Is there a way to prevent duplicate assemblies from being loaded into `typesToRegister`? Or, is there a way to prevent the code from attempting to load the duplicate into the modelBuilder:

```
  foreach (Type type in typesToRegister)
    {
        dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(configurationInstance); // Exception thrown here
    }
```

**GroupMap.cs**

```
public class GroupMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Group>
{
    public GroupMap()
    {
        Property(group => group.Name).IsRequired();
        HasMany(group => group.Roles)
            .WithMany(role => role.Groups)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("GroupId");
                m.MapRightKey("RoleId");
                m.ToTable("GroupRoles");
            });
        HasMany(group => group.Members)
            .WithMany(user => user.Groups)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("GroupId");
                m.MapRightKey("PersonId");
                m.ToTable("GroupMembers");
            });

    }
}
```

**Group.cs**

```
public class Group : BaseEntity
{
    private ICollection<Person> _members;
    private ICollection<Role> _roles;

    public Group()
    {
        _members = new HashSet<Person>();
        _roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    }
    [Display(Name = "Group Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Group Name is required.")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Group Name allows only 100 characters.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Person> Members
    {
        get { return _members;  } 
        set { _members = value;  }
    }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles
    {
        get { return _roles; }
        set { _roles = value; }
    }
}
```

**BaseDbContext.cs**

```
public class BaseDbContext<TContext> : DbContext where TContext : DbContext, IDbContext, IObjectContextAdapter
{
    static BaseDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<TContext>(null);
    }

    public void RunConventions(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder, Type assemblyClassType)
    {
        // Change default conventions for cascade deletes
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        // Id property in everyclass is named class + Id  (i.e CustomerId, JobId, VendorId)
        // Id is always first column in table
        // Could also explicitly determine as key using .Configure(p => p.IsKey() but EF already looks for property of name Id as primary key
        modelBuilder.Properties()
          .Where(p => p.Name == "Id")
          .Configure(p => p.HasColumnOrder(0).HasColumnName((p.ClrPropertyInfo.ReflectedType == null ? "" : p.ClrPropertyInfo.ReflectedType.Name) + "Id"));

        // Add Domain Entity Mapping Configurations
        //var typesToRegister = Assembly.GetAssembly(assemblyClassType).GetTypes()
        //  .Where(type => type.Namespace != null);

        var typesToRegister = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(DbContext)).GetTypes()
            .Where(type => type.Namespace != null && type.Namespace.Equals(typeof(BaseDbContext<TContext>).Namespace))
            .Where(type => type.BaseType.IsGenericType && type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>));
        foreach (Type type in typesToRegister)
        {
            dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(configurationInstance);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide exact error message?

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk Done.

Comment: What is the line that is executing when the exception happens?

Comment: @StevePy Added code comment in second block. `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(configurationInstance)`. I am preparing a screenshot to show the ResultsView.

Comment: @JWeezy I think you should check if typesToRegister each type is of IEntityTypeConfiguration.

Comment: @KrishnaDhungana Can you please post an answer with code example?

Comment: @JWeezy is it .efcore? What version ?

Comment: Can You add the EntityTypeConfiguration definition for GroupMap? Something looks a bit sus there, also, the entity for Group.  This looks like it may be having an issue with a complex type.

Comment: @KrishnaDhungana EF 4.5.2. We are not using Core.

Comment: @StevePy added GroupMap.cs and Group.cs to the question.

Comment: Sorry, had seen those in the linked question. I think the issue will be with identifying the entity type configurations. I posted the code in an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. After digging around in the Results View, and with help of a friend, we found that the duplicates are not actually duplicates - they have different GUIDs. What distinguished the two is that one was nested while the other was not nested. The duplicate that was not loaded had an IsNested = True. So, the solution was to filter out where IsNested == false

```
    var typesToRegister = Assembly.GetAssembly(assemblyClassType).GetTypes()
      .Where(type => type.Namespace != null && type.IsNested == false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue will be with:

```
var typesToRegister = Assembly.GetAssembly(assemblyClassType).GetTypes()
    .Where(type => type.Namespace != null)
```

This will pull all class definitions, not just IEntityTypeConfiguration implementations.

Try updating this to:

```
var typesToRegister = Assembly.GetAssembly(assemblyClassType).GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEntityTypeConfiguration<>))).ToList();
```

This should just attempt to register the entity type configurations.

Another small detail is that you should probably add an `Ignore(galaxyUser => galaxyUser.IsSysAdmin);` as well.

Edit: Sorry, for EF 6 you don't need to explicitly specify the types to register, that is an EF Core limiation. For EF 6:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(assemblyClassType));
    }
```

Comment: I am getting a following error: The type or namespace name 'IEntityTypeConfiguration<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I did some searching online and IEntityTypeConfiguration is being reference in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. Please note that this is **not** a .NET CORE project - it is ASP.NET MVC. Kindly, can you think of any other potential solutions?

Comment: AH, my bad... I mistook that for EF Core.. I will adjust for EF 6. (Much simpler)

Comment: This seems to work, but I am getting another exception right after the call to OnModelCreating completes. I will take a look at this tomorrow to see if it is related. If not, that is a new question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: TL DR: It appears I need the RunConvetions() method. The RunConventions() method appears to append the assembly name to the default ID column that EF assumes for all tables. So, were EF defines ID as the default primary key column for all tables, the actual project defines the primary key as Table + Id. In the comments, table = assembly. So, without it, another error is tripped by a subsequent query builder.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add all configurations, then, I think with EF 4.5.x, you can use `AddFromAssembly`,

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);
//OR typeof(DBContext).Assembly
```

Regarding the issue, could you try like this:

```
var typesToRegister = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(DbContext)).GetTypes()
.Where(type => type.Namespace != null
       && type.Namespace.Equals(typeof(DBContext).Namespace))
      .Where(type => type.BaseType.IsGenericType
      && type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == 
         typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>));

foreach (var type in typesToRegister)
{
  dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
  modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(configurationInstance);
}
```

Comment: I tried making the change, but that did not work either. There are zero elements in the Results View.